# Errors after following a Scala + Play tutorial

Tags: scala

I have a few errors in my basic application that I was hoping you could help solve.

I am following this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/your-first-application-with-play-and-scala)

and this is the code I wind up with:

This is my `app/controllers/HomeController.scala` file:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page.
   *
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def greet(name: String) = Action {
    Ok("Hello " + name)
  }

  def loginCount(userId: String) = Action {
    Ok(14)
  }
}
```

And this is my `conf/routes` file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ScalaRouting
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

GET     /greet                      controllers.HomeController.greet(name)

GET     /user/:userId/login/count          controllers.HomeController.loginCount(userId)
```

But when I go to `localhost:9000`, I get:

```
 /Users/jwan/Desktop/programming/scala_play/playstarter/app/controllers/HomeController.scala:30:7: Cannot write an instance of Int to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Int]
[error]     Ok(14)
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application -

! @77jnoh18m - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
```

and the /greet has an error to. The page shows:

> Bad Request
>   For request 'GET /greet' [Missing parameter: name]

Lastly, I am having trouble understanding the syntax of the `routes` file. What kind of file is this? When we write:

`GET     /greet                      controllers.HomeController.greet(name)`

Is it a `GET` method with two arguments? What is going on? How is this being interpreted?

**EDIT**

So I got this to work:

```
GET     /greet                      controllers.HomeController.greet(name)
```

and then going here: `http://localhost:9000/greet?name=jeff`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax in the routes file is wrong, you need to do something like this:

```
GET     /greet/:name                      controllers.HomeController.greet(name)
```

You specify variables in your route, and how they should be handed to the controller function.  I don't know the specifics, but that file then gets compiled into a Scala file.